# downloadable link in html5

Tags: html, video

I am trying to make an audio/video file in html downloadable but it opens in another tab.

I used the anchor tag  to link to a file in both instances.

```
<div id="video">
            <figure>
            <video src="video/myfile.mp4"
                    poster="images/sackboy.jpg"
                    type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'
                    preload
                    loop
                    controls
                    none
                    width="600"
                    height="300"
                    id="videotag">
            </video>
                <figcaption>
                  <em>This video meant to enlighten people on games and how they are made.</em>
                </figcaption>
                <a href="http//:video/myfile.mp4">Download</a>
            </figure>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the target attribute. Normally, it will be opened in the same frame.

Maybe if you add _self it will work:

```
<a href="link" target="_self">Link</a>
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: I tried using the target="_self" attribute in the anchor tag but it opened in the same tab instead. Anything else you can recommend?

Comment: Maybe it has problems with the url?
 http//:video/myfile.mp4

Comment: Should i remove the hyper link to just a link that links to local content?

Comment: still... removed the http//: and just used the local path link.

Comment: What i mean is, i guess the browser maybe thinks it is a local URL.

http://:video isn't a correct url..

Is it a website online? --> http://domain.com/videos/
Is it a website offline (server)? -->  http://localhost/videos/
Is it a website offline (only html) --> c:/videos/ (or osx url,...)

Comment: it is not online. the link is a folder that's on my desktop.

Comment: osx ? windows? linux?